# Optra5 (Reno) bolt size on valve cover

Tags: suzuki, valve-cover, bolts, optra5

I lost the 2 bolt on the cover that hide the spark plugs wires.
I live in Canada and no store knows the size.
Does anyone know?

And can I drive without this cap?

[image]

Thank you

2004 Chevrolet Optra5 (Suzuki Reno) 2.0L

Answer (score 1):

The picture you are showing is misleading because it includes the valve cover.

As long as you are referring to just the part outlined below, yes, you can run the engine without it. It is a simple cover to hide the wires and keep dirt out if that area.

[image]

Comment: I'd guess the hold down bolts are m6x1.0x20 or 30 OP would have to figure out the length.

Comment: Looks like it, Ben. I will try and give update.